# Visual Studio 2012 Database Project Diagram View

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I started to work with the Visual Studio 2012 and I created a new database project.
It seems very useful, but I cannot find any option to see my tables in a diagram view.
Where I can see all tables and the relationships belong them.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature in Visual Studio Database Projects, and there never has been.

Answer (score 0):

In the Data Sources pane, if you click on the icon called "Edit DataSet with Designer"  You can create a diagram.  That may be as close as you can get.